# why do i get NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, friendly-id

I want my trade page to show a list of every `Item` that a user has added to their cart, and I'm having trouble understanding why this implementation is giving me a NoMethodError

So in the `#show` action of my TradesController I have a `trade_ids` variable that contains an array of added items returned by `$redis.smembers current_user_trade`. I then use this to perform a lookup on the id of each item, and loop through the instance variable in my view.

My Trades Controller:

```
class TradesController < ApplicationController
 def show
  trade_ids = $redis.smembers current_user_trade
  @trade_items = Item.find(trade_ids)
 end

 def add
  $redis.sadd current_user_trade, params[:item_id]
  render json: current_user.trade_count, status: 200
 end

 def remove
  $redis.srem current_user_trade, params[:item_id]
  render json: current_user.trade_count, status: 200
 end


 private

 def current_user_trade
  "trade#{current_user.id}"
 end
end
```

Here's the method I'm using to add items to `current_user_trade`:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :slug, use: [:slugged, :finders]

 def slug
  [artist.parameterize, title.parameterize].join("-")
 end

 def trade_action(current_user_id)
  if $redis.sismember "trade#{current_user_id}", id
   "Remove from"
  else
   "Add to"
  end
 end
end
```

My routes:

```
resource :trade, only: [:show] do
 put 'add/:item_id', to: 'trades#add', as: :add_to
 put 'remove/:item_id', to: 'trades#remove', as: :remove_from
end
```

And then in my trades view I've got a basic:

```
<% @trade_items.each do |item| %>
 <p><%= item.title %></p>
 etc
<% end %>
```

My initial thought is that this had something to do with the fact that I've been using FriendlyId for slug generation. But according to [FriendlyId's doc](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), adding `:finders` to the slug declaration in my Item model should reenable lookups by id. But it's not.

I also tried refactoring this so that it used my Items :slug, but that too was to no avail.

Comment: Can you please post `$redis.smembers current_user_trade` array. it helps us more

Comment: what do you mean post the array? i think i misunderstand. rails knows the 4 items i've added to that set

Comment: I mean to say that print your  `$redis.smembers current_user_trade` object

Comment: I think I said that in the OP? The part of the error code that says `name-title, name-title, name-title, name-title` is what's in the object.

Comment: So if you are getting the name from `$redis.smembers current_user_trade` then why are you trying to find a record with `id`?

Comment: The thing is, I'm not able to see in my code where I'm trying to perform a lookup with `id`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147670/discussion-between-mayur-shah-and-sabaeus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out it was cached. I switched from storing `item_id` to `item_slug` halfway through, and needed to run `redis-cli flushall` to get it to store and access the right data.